# passing pointer to function and using realloc

Tags: c++, c, pointers, malloc, realloc

I want to pass a pointer to a function which will call a second function that will use realloc.
The issue is that realloc is returning NULL.

I don't know if the mistake is in the numbers of * in the function call or something else.

Could you please help me ?

The code:

```
int main(){

// some code.
clause_t* ptr; //clause_t is a structure i declared.

//Some work including the initial allocation of ptr (which is working).

assignLonely(matSAT, ic.nbClause, ic.nbVar, ptr); //the issue is here.

//Some other work
}

void assignLonely(int** matSAT, int nbClause, int nbVar, clause_t* ptr)
 {

   int i = 0, j = 0;
   int cpt = 0;
   int indice = -1; 

for (i = 0; i < nbClause ; ++i)
{
    j = 0;
    cpt = 0;
    while((j < nbVar) && (cpt < 2))
    {
        if (matSAT[i][j] != 0)
        {
            cpt++;
        }
        else
        {
            indice = j;
        }

        if (cpt < 2)
        {
            deleteClause(indice, &ptr);
        }

        j++;
    }
}
}

void deleteClause(int indiceClause, clause_t** ptr)
{
    int i = indiceClause;
    int nbElt = sizeof((*ptr))/sizeof((*ptr)[0]);
    int tailleElt = sizeof((*ptr)[0]);

while(i+1 < nbElt)
{
    (*ptr)[i] = (*ptr)[i+1];
    i++;
}

*ptr = (clause_t*)realloc(*ptr, (nbElt-1)*tailleElt);
if (*ptr == NULL)
{
    fprintf(stderr, "Erreur reallocation\n");
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
}

}
```

Comment: `int nbElt = sizeof((*ptr))/sizeof((*ptr)[0]);` This doesn't do what you think it does. `*ptr`  is just another pointer, not the array. So this will be 1 or zero, depending on the sizeof clause_t. And your realloc will be of zero bytes, which is why it returns null. A debugger or a few printfs (e.g. of `nElt`) would show you this, and would also be a good idea before asking SO

Comment: please select a language tag - C and C++ are different. (Probably remove the C++ tag)

Comment: You need `#include <stdlib.h>` to ensure that `realloc` functions correctly

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to declarae function `assignLonely` similarly to function `deleteClause` like

```
void assignLonely(int** matSAT, int nbClause, int nbVar, clause_t** ptr);
```

if you want that changes of ptr in the function would be stored in the original object in main.

Also take into account that this statement

```
int nbElt = sizeof((*ptr))/sizeof((*ptr)[0]);
```

is wrong. 
Expression `sizeof((*ptr))` will return the size of the pointer. Pointers do not keep information about how many elements in arrays they point to.

So expression

```
(nbElt-1)
```

can be equal to zero or even be negative.

Comment: OK, but that's not the reason realloc returns null

Comment: Thanks guys, but i l already used something like this here:

void initMatSAT(int** matSAT)
{
 int nbRow = sizeof(matSAT)/sizeof(matSAT[0]); 
 int nbColumn = sizeof(matSAT[0])/sizeof(matSAT[0][0]); 
// rest of the work.

And it worked.

Comment: @user3564164 matSAT has type int ** So its size is either 4 bytes or 8 bytes depending on the environment where the program is compiled. matSAT[0] has type int * that is it is also a pointer. So the result of sizeof( matSAT ) / sizeof( matSAT[0] ) will be always equal to 1.

Comment: @user3564164, print nEblt. And you will see. Pointers in C just don't track the eize of what they point to, no matter what you think "worked" before.

Comment: you are right Paul,
I just tried some printfs and it printed 1 as you just said.
So, if i understand, i will be obliged to pass the dimensions of my array to my function instead of trying to calculate them with sizeof() ?
The thing is, i just tried to understand the difference between where it worked fine and where it didn't.

Comment: @user3564164 Yes, you need also to pass the information how many elements of the dynamically allocated array the pointer points to. Also it seems that initial value of the pointer shall be NULL.

Comment: @VladfromMoscow I'm sorry if i didn't get you but, what do you mean by the initial value of the pointer should be NULL ?
As i mentioned, ptr was already allocated using malloc() (it points initially on 91elts) i wanted to use realloc to delete one element of the array (the last one) and keep the rest of the elements.

Comment: @user3564164 If it was already allocated using malloc then no problem I mean the following declaration  clause_t* ptr = NULL; Only as I wrote in my posy you have to pass the pointer by pointer that in main to free the changed pointer.

Comment: VladfromMoscow, Paul Thanks a lot guys, it works now that i pass the size to the function.
However, i'm wondering, how to know whether using sizeof() to determine the size of an array should work like with int** matSAT or nor like with clause_t* (i mean before trying it). In other words, is there any general rule ?

Comment: @user3564164: The "general rule" is that the `sizeof` operator can be used to determine the size of an array when and only when you apply it to an actual array. If you apply it to a pointer, it will never "work" for that purpose. So, it won't "work" with `int ** matSAT`, with `clause_t *`, or with any other pointer.

Comment: @user3564164 Operator sizeof returns size of an object in bytes. If an object is an array then sizeof returns the size of the array (in bytes). If an object is a pointer sizeof returns the size of the pointer.